# Comparing data from 2 jsonp calls

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I would like to be able to compare information from 2 separate jsonp calls. I am currently using $.getJSON but I have also tried $.ajax with no luck. I was under the impression the problem was the $.getJSON call was being preformed asynchronously, and that was the issue. That is why i tried the $.ajax async: false, but it still does not work. I would like to do something like this.

```
$.getJSON('url1', function(data){ var a = data.information };
$.getJSON('url2', function(data){ var b = data.information };
if(a === b) { whatever };
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP is always asynchronous by its nature ( and even if it wasn't you should still use asynchronous version; `async:false` is a **root of all evil** ). You cannot change that. In order to accomplish what you are trying to do you can use `$.when`:

```
var requests = [];
var data1, data2;

requests.push(
    $.getJSON( 'url1', function(data) { data1 = data.information; } )
);
requests.push(
    $.getJSON( 'url2', function(data) { data2 = data.information; } )
);

$.when.apply( $, requests ).then( function( ) {
    if (data1===data2) {
        // do something
    }
});
```